# While running "package-refresh-content" show me this. Why? Emacs 28.1

Tags: debugging, package

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Location https//elpa.gnu.org/packages/ is not a url nor an absolute file name")
  signal(error ("Location https//elpa.gnu.org/packages/ is not a url nor an absolute file name"))
  package--with-response-buffer-1("https//elpa.gnu.org/packages/" #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x15f5309650fab0c5>) :file "archive-contents" :async nil :error-func$
  package--download-one-archive(("elpa" . "https//elpa.gnu.org/packages/") "archive-contents" nil)
  package--download-and-read-archives(nil)
  package-refresh-contents()
  funcall-interactively(package-refresh-contents)
  call-interactively(package-refresh-contents record nil)
  command-execute(package-refresh-contents record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "package-refresh-contents" "package-re")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "package-refresh-contents" "package-re")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Comment: You need a ":" after https I guess

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer. It was a typo on my part: `https//` should have been `https://`, which was pointed out by some wise people on reddit ...

https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/u9rp9r/please_shed_some_light_why_i_am_getting_this/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This is a link-only answer.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Please post the relevant information directly in your answer so that it is self-contained.  Links can disappear and even become security hazards.

Comment: Thanks whoever edited the answer and put the explanation above the link. I think @Fran